# What is (High-Low) and (Open-Close) spread?

Tags: equities

Spread is the difference between Bid and Ask. I'm confused what is High-Low Spread and Open-Close spread?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply the difference between the two values.

High-Low gives you an idea about the total price movement over the tick period, Open-Close gives you an indication of the direction of the move. If Open-Close is negative, the price went up, and vice versa. High-Low obviously is always positive.

Comment: Open-Close spread means: (Spread during the day's Open) minus (Spread during the day's Close) ??

Comment: yeah, thats correct.

Comment: Not that phi was wrong, but I suspect the OP was confused by the word "spread". He thought that "spread" could only be used for the ask-minus-bid. It looks like the screenshot is also using "spread" for the high-minus-low and the open-minus-close. These are not related to the bid and the ask at all. The OP's comment to this answer was not correct. The comment seems to say "open-close spread" = (ask at open minus bid at open) - (ask at close minus bid at close). That would be incorrect.